# OpenAM 14.5.1 Login

Tags: openam

I just deployed OpenAM-14.5.1.war into Tomcat on my Mac and went through the initial configuration setup (create new/default configuration). The setup completed successfully. I was then led to the login page. I provided the same username/password as I did during the setup but getting the **Authentication Failed** message. Any idea why?

Comment: For future purpose , please specify which OpenAM fork you are using as there is no THE OpenAM. There are several forks. Personally I find it a bit strange that they all claim to be 'OpenAM'.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The issue was - I was using a browser window that disabled cookies. Once I started using normal browser window, I was able to login successfully.